# The response from the identity provider is not valid

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

`saml20.implementation.SAMLFeedbackException: The response from the identity provider is not valid.`

Trying to configure SAML2.0 using WSO2 5.4.1 Identity Server

**Here is the Metadata file from WSO2 IS.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><EntityDescriptor 
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="localhost">
<IDPSSODescriptor 
protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
validUntil="2018-02-28T06:02:51.018Z"><KeyDescriptor use="signing"><KeyInfo 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><X509Data>
<X509Certificate> 
MIIDSTCCAjGgAwIBAgIEAoLQ/TANBgkqhki....WCCq4ZuXl6wVsUz1iE61suO5yWi8=
</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></KeyDescriptor><SingleLogoutService 
Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" 
Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" 
ResponseLocation="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
<NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-
format:unspecified</NameIDFormat><SingleSignOnService 
Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/><SingleSignOnService 
Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" 
Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/></IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

**Below file is SP generated from SAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="http://localhost:7337/" 
xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
<md:SPSSODescriptor 
protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor>
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
MIIDNjCCAh6gAwIBAgI....7YzPhQmQo7pVpn1YLvlNk
IJyZ9RkmZyI+h6ayztkOgc+scflN/j2fdDOufg==</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-
Redirect" Location="http://localhost:7337/SSO/logout"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-
POST" Location="http://localhost:7337/SSO/logout"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService 
Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
Location="http://localhost:7337/SSO/assertion" index="1"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService 
Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" 
Location="http://localhost:7337/SSO/assertion" index="2"/>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
<md:Organization>
<md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">NNN</md:OrganizationName>
<md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">NNN</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
<md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="en">www.xyz.com</md:OrganizationURL>
</md:Organization>
<md:ContactPerson contactType="administrative">
<md:GivenName>Test</md:GivenName>
<md:SurName>K</md:SurName>
<md:EmailAddress>test.k@gmail.com</md:EmailAddress>
</md:ContactPerson>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

When I am running application it is redirecting me to wso2 login page. After giving username and password and on click on Login button I'm getting this error.

Comment: Hi there can be many reasons. try looking in the logs and see if you can find more detail. If not try setting a the log level to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it after lot of struggle and working properly.

I was missing a check box to check under SAML2 Web SSO Configuration, see the image below

[image]